# Quantmod/getOptionChain Error in .Date(Exp/86400) : could not find function ".Date"

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm getting an error when running getOptionChain from quantmod package.

The code should get Option chain data and subset into a new list that contains only the puts.

The error I get is: **Error in .Date(Exp/86400) : could not find function ".Date"**

Same code, sometimes runs without error. If I shorten the list of Symbols, there's no error, but the error as far as I know is not related to a specific symbol, because I made to run successfully. Seems random but frequent error.

All symbols are weekly expirations and the desired output is the next weekly expiration, so from my understanding, there's no need to specify a exp date.

```
library(quantmod)

library(xts)

Symbols<-c ("AA","AAL","AAOI","AAPL","ABBV","ABC","ABNB","ABT","ACAD","ACB","ACN","ADBE","ADI","ADM","ADP",
"ADSK","AEO","AFL","AFRM","AG","AGNC","AHT","AIG","AKAM","ALGN","AMAT","AMBA","AMC","AMD","AMGN",
"AMPX","AMRN","AMRS","AMZN","ANET","ANF","ANY","APA","APO","APPH","APPS","APRN","APT","AR","ARVL")

Options.20221118 <- lapply(Symbols, getOptionChain)

names(Options.20221118) <- Symbols

only_puts_list <- lapply(Options.20221118, function(x) x$puts)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that. You are likely using an old version of R.  Update it.  Also note that quantmod already pulls in xts so you don't need a `library` statement for it.

Comment: I updated R version to latest one and worked fine. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading to R 4.2.2 the issue is fixed.